# Getting "Script function not found" when trying to use standalone script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Apps Scripts. My background is in mainframes so the terminology and concepts of Java-like languages are a bit foreign to me. Here's my situation. I have several Google spreadsheets that are very similar, but a little different from each other. I want to use the same standalone Apps Script to reset the fields in these Google spreadsheets. The script I have written works fine when container-bound but when I put it in a Google Apps Script (project?) file in MyDrive and try to execute it from there using a button assigned to the function name resetRounds, I get the "Script not found" error. I don't want to have a copy of the same script in each spreadsheet. Do I have to do anything special to connect the project file to the spreadsheets? What could be causing the "not found" condition? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

This is the script as it exists in the Google Apps Script project file.

```
function resetRounds() {


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssName = ss.getName();
  var shRounds = ss.getSheetByName("Rounds");
  var shLog = ss.getSheetByName('Print-Log').getName();
  var shDDList = ss.getSheetByName("DD-Lists"); 

  // Restore SVE team name from DD-Lists sheet 
  var source = shDDList.getRange("A3"); /* Team name should be in cell A3 */
  var destn  = shRounds.getRange("D3"); /* copy it to Team Name cell */
  source.copyTo(destn, {contentsOnly:true}); /* copy contents only, not the formatting */
 
  // Reset visitor team name and Captains to trigger cell conditional formatting */ 
  destn = shRounds.getRange("L3").activate().setValue('None');
  destn = shRounds.getRange("N4").activate().setValue('None');
  
  
  // Set the date to 1/1/2001 to trigger conditional formatting
  // Week number will show as blank (0) when special date 1/1/2001 is used
  source = shDDList.getRange("A51"); /* Special date should be in cell A51 */
  destn  = shRounds.getRange("Q3");  /* Only the first cell needs to be selected */ 
  source.copyTo(destn, {contentsOnly:true}); /* copy contents only, not the formatting */

  // Restore times from DD-Lists sheet 
  source = shDDList.getRange("A5"); /* Round 1 time should be in cell A5 */
  destn  = shRounds.getRange("C6"); /* copy it to Round 1 cell */
  source.copyTo(destn, {contentsOnly:true}); /* copy contents only, not the formatting */

  source = shDDList.getRange("A6"); /* Round 2 time should be in cell A6 */
  destn  = shRounds.getRange("L6"); /* copy it to Round 2 cell */
  source.copyTo(destn, {contentsOnly:true}); /* copy contents only, not the formatting */

 // Reset court numbers 
  ss.getRange("B8:B13").activate().setValue('Y');  /* Court number 1 */
  ss.getRange("B15:B20").activate().setValue('2'); /* Court number 2 */
  ss.getRange("B22:B27").activate().setValue('3'); /* Court number 3 */
  ss.getRange("B29:B34").activate().setValue('4'); /* Court number 4 */
  ss.getRange("B36:B41").activate().setValue('5'); /* Court number 5 */
  ss.getRange("B43:B48").activate().setValue('6'); /* Court number 6 */
  // Clear round 1 and round 2 player names 
  ss.getRange("C8:C48").activate().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true}); 
  ss.getRange("E8:E48").activate().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true}); 
  ss.getRange("L8:L48").activate().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true}); 
  ss.getRange("N8:N48").activate().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true}); 
  // Clear round 1 and round 2 scores
  ss.getRange("G8:H48").activate().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true}); 
  ss.getRange("P8:Q48").activate().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true}); 
  // Clear scorekeeper names
  ss.getRange("C56:E59").activate().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true}); 
  ss.getRange("C61:E62").activate().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true}); 
  /* Reset cursor to Visitor */
  ss.getRange('L3:N3').activate();


  }
```

Comment: I believe buttons on a spreadsheet can only be connected to script within the one of the projects contained in the spreadsheet not standalone projects

Comment: You might be able to use a library.

Comment: Could you explain what a "project" is and how it relates to the spreadsheet? I have a Google Apps Script file created with the standalone script in it. Is that the same as a library?

Comment: A project contains script.  If a project is standalone then it has no container.  If a project has a container then it can be attached to a slide,document or a spreadsheet and you can use methods that refer to getActive.  With standalone scripts they have to open documents and spreadsheet byid or url.

Answer (score 0):

#### Proposed workaround

You wish to run a script on a subset of sheets from a central location using a button. Unfortunately, the button aspect can make things more complicated (a few suggestions at the end), but if the button is not necessary and you are willing to run it from the script editor (or on a time-based trigger), then the below should work:

```js
function resetRounds() {
  var IDs = ["[SS ID 1]", "[SS ID 2]", "[SS ID 3]"]; // Add the spreadsheet IDs here

  // This `forEach` loop will go through each id
  IDs.forEach((id) => {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id); // Instead of calling `getActive` you are opening by Ids
    
    // This part of the script is unchanged vvvv

    var ssName = ss.getName();
    var shRounds = ss.getSheetByName("Rounds");
    var shLog = ss.getSheetByName("Print-Log").getName();
    var shDDList = ss.getSheetByName("DD-Lists");

    // Restore SVE team name from DD-Lists sheet
    var source = shDDList.getRange("A3"); /* Team name should be in cell A3 */
    var destn = shRounds.getRange("D3"); /* copy it to Team Name cell */
    source.copyTo(destn, {
      contentsOnly: true,
    }); /* copy contents only, not the formatting */

    // Reset visitor team name and Captains to trigger cell conditional formatting */
    destn = shRounds.getRange("L3").activate().setValue("None");
    destn = shRounds.getRange("N4").activate().setValue("None");

    // Set the date to 1/1/2001 to trigger conditional formatting
    // Week number will show as blank (0) when special date 1/1/2001 is used
    source = shDDList.getRange("A51"); /* Special date should be in cell A51 */
    destn = shRounds.getRange(
      "Q3"
    ); /* Only the first cell needs to be selected */
    source.copyTo(destn, {
      contentsOnly: true,
    }); /* copy contents only, not the formatting */

    // Restore times from DD-Lists sheet
    source = shDDList.getRange("A5"); /* Round 1 time should be in cell A5 */
    destn = shRounds.getRange("C6"); /* copy it to Round 1 cell */
    source.copyTo(destn, {
      contentsOnly: true,
    }); /* copy contents only, not the formatting */

    source = shDDList.getRange("A6"); /* Round 2 time should be in cell A6 */
    destn = shRounds.getRange("L6"); /* copy it to Round 2 cell */
    source.copyTo(destn, {
      contentsOnly: true,
    }); /* copy contents only, not the formatting */

    // Reset court numbers
    ss.getRange("B8:B13").activate().setValue("Y"); /* Court number 1 */
    ss.getRange("B15:B20").activate().setValue("2"); /* Court number 2 */
    ss.getRange("B22:B27").activate().setValue("3"); /* Court number 3 */
    ss.getRange("B29:B34").activate().setValue("4"); /* Court number 4 */
    ss.getRange("B36:B41").activate().setValue("5"); /* Court number 5 */
    ss.getRange("B43:B48").activate().setValue("6"); /* Court number 6 */
    // Clear round 1 and round 2 player names
    ss.getRange("C8:C48")
      .activate()
      .clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
    ss.getRange("E8:E48")
      .activate()
      .clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
    ss.getRange("L8:L48")
      .activate()
      .clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
    ss.getRange("N8:N48")
      .activate()
      .clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
    // Clear round 1 and round 2 scores
    ss.getRange("G8:H48")
      .activate()
      .clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
    ss.getRange("P8:Q48")
      .activate()
      .clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
    // Clear scorekeeper names
    ss.getRange("C56:E59")
      .activate()
      .clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
    ss.getRange("C61:E62")
      .activate()
      .clear({ contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true });
    /* Reset cursor to Visitor */
    ss.getRange("L3:N3").activate();

    // This part of the script is unchanged ^^^^

  });
}
```

All that has happened here is that instead of calling `getActive` to open the spreadsheet it calls `openById`. It gets the IDs from an array or list of the IDs initialized at the top of the script. Then the `forEach` method is called on that array, which will repeat a certain operation on each item in that list. We use each item to call `openById`. This will run the script for each spreadsheet, as long as you have edit access to them.

#### Assigning it to a button

You could have a sheet with a bound script as you have, except that all this sheet is for is to have a button. It wouldn't have any data itself, its just for the user to launch the script without having to go into the script editor and running it manually.

#### Running it on a trigger

You could also look into triggers (linked below) that would run this 'master' script every day automatically for instance. It would also email you in case of failure.

#### References

- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)
- [timeBased()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#timeBased())
- [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/storing_data_spreadsheets#triggers)
- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)